# get the text next to checkboxes in javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way that I can get "Enable Recruiters to directly contact me" in Javascript or JQuery when the checkbox checked?

I know I can get the value easily, but how about the text beside that which can be in a lable?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rec" id="rec" value="ON"><label for='rec'>Enable Recruiters to directly contact me</label>
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the change event and use the event source object to call next on it to get the label next to checkbox.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrNU9/)**

```
$('#rec').change(function(){
   if(this.checked)
    alert($(this).next().text())    
})
```